# Prerequisites for some topics on two dimmensional ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am an Electrical Engineer student and I want to do an summer course on two dimmensional ODEs. The reference book is Arnold and the subjects that will be cover it's:

Vector fields, fixed points, uniqueness and existence of solution, linear diff. eq's on R^2, exponential (I guees that would be e^At), classification of critical points (complexification), limit sets, Poincare-Bendixon, vector fields on toro bi-dimensional (without singularity and dense orbits) and vector fields on bi-dimensional sphere and there are more two topics that I dont know exacly how to translate (one, I believe, it's index of critical points). If anyone here speaks portuguese, the link for all the informations of the course it's: http://verao.icmc.usp.br/. On this link, just check for "equações diferencias em dimensão dois".

obs: the course is on senior urdergraduate level.
obs²: This course will starts in the next 4 months, and I'm already studying Real Analysis on R for it and I have some notions in Topology.
obs³: if someone help, please be specific and just dont say, for instance, "linear algebra".